# the specified module 'pswindowsupdate' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: windows, powershell

Window updates are always saying checking for updates and process is running without any update install. Hence, I am trying to install window updates using the Windows PowerShell button. However, I have found the error below when I used the following command in Powershell:

```
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```

> the specified module 'pswindowsupdate' was not loaded because no valid
>   module file was found in any module directory

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you download the module and save it to
here: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

or
here: `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with the Security & Compliance PowerShell when I ran:

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Looking into it further I discovered that you can use the "Find-Module" cmdlet to search and install it:

```
Find-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement | Install-Module
```

In your situation you'll want to execute the following:

```
Find-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.3#example-1-find-and-install-a-module

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I have downloaded the "PSWindowupdate.zip" from here. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules which fixed the issue.

Comment: It had fixed for me so I suppose to add it as an answer.